# Can't log into Careers - as a potential recruiter

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

"Oops something bad happened" - on Careers - Can't log using either googleid.

Nasty web errors not turned on page when logging in with a new email/pwd combination.

Answer (score 3):

Yup - something's up; we're looking into it. Will update answer once resolved.

**Edit**
Regular OpenID log in is functional again. We had a router outage that interrupted the server to server communication required by OpenID. Email/password log in is still not functional, still working on that one.

**Edit 2**
And... Email / password log-in is back.

Apologies for any inconvenience and thanks for bearing with us.

**Edit 3**
Or... so we thought... We're still having intermittent issues with email / password login. Update will follow.

**Final Update**
As of about 5PM yesterday evening all is officially well again.